# UICollectionView - Scrolling to first cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm making use of UICollectionView and I need to scroll to first cell after click in a button.

The button is located in a (big) header section in my collection view... when clicking int it, I need scroll to my first cell located bellow of this button.

I created a action of this button, but I don't know how to scroll to first UICollectionViewCell.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use this delegate method, setting the indexPath at the first position:

Swift

```
self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0), 
                                                atScrollPosition: .Top, 
                                                        animated: true)
```

Swift 3

```
self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), 
                                  at: .top, 
                            animated: true)
```

Objective-C

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] 
                            atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop
                                    animated:YES];
```

Change `UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop` if you want to scroll and stop at a different position

Comment: Swift 3 version: `self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)`

Comment: This will scroll to the first visible cell, not to the first cell in the collectionView.

Comment: @Alex, No, it scrolls to the first cell in the collectionView.

Answer (score 14):

It might be possible to use the UIScrollView related property

```
collectionView.contentOffset.x = 0
```

Comment: This one worked best. It doesn't animate but scrollToItem doesn't factor in any edge insets you have.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution works fine for me:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
     self.collectionView?.contentOffset.x = 0
})
```

It scrolls to the first item and the contentInset can be seen as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for Objective - C

```
        [self.restaurantCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Default CollectionView Delgeate...

```
- (void)scrollToItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) {
            self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work reliably on all devices and correctly handle iPhone X-style safe areas.

```
let top = CGPoint(
  x: collectionView.contentOffset.x,
  y: collectionView.adjustedContentInset.top
)
collectionView.setContentOffset(top, animated: false)
```

*(This scrolls vertically to the top but you could easily make it scroll to the top-left if you wanted.)*